# Where to ask questions about network addresses etc?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Okay I had no idea how to name this in the title but I'll explain my question. I want to ask a question about this:

> I have a laptop and I am hosting a game server at the moment at home.
>   Now my problem is while portforwarding I have to add in my ipv4 address
>   while portforwarding. 
>   My laptop is connected with wifi and my ipv4 address is changing everytime
>   I boot my laptop.

So I am actually wondering where to ask this. I have no experience with https://serverfault.com/ whatsoever, so my first thought was for https://superuser.com/ but I remembered **Serverfault**. Now where should I ask this?

Comment: Definitely not serverfault. This is not a professional IT environment, and you'll be hounded off the site for asking about your "server" with a wifi dynamic IP...

Comment: This is definitely a super user question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ServerFault...

From the Help section of ServerFault :

> it is not about…

- **Anything in a home or development environment**
- Product, service, or learning material recommendations
- Career, salary, personnel, employment, or formal education
- Licensing, legal advice, and circumvention of security or policy
- Unauthorized hacking, password cracking, or system misuse

**So right there you know it's not for you.**

---

### SuperUser...

From the Help section of SuperUser :

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

- computer hardware,
- computer software, or
- personal and home computer networking

This is more like what you want to ask. You have it. **SuperUser it is.**